# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am trying to use embeddable annotation to store different values in one object to be persisted in one table.

I have two classes:
userDetails:

```
package org.hibernet.src;
@Entity
@Table (name="UserDetails")
 public class userDetails {
 @Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dob;
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
private String userName;
@Embedded
private Address address;

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

}
```

2. Address class which is embeddable class:

   ```
    @Embeddable

    public class Address {

   @Column(nullable=true)
   private String street;

   @Column(nullable=true)
   private String city;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String state;


   public String getStreet() {
   return street;
   }
   public void setStreet(String street) {
   this.street = street;
   }
   public String getCity() {
       return city;
   }
    public void setCity(String city) {
       this.city = city;
    }
   public String getState() {
   return state;
   }
   public void setState(String state) {
       this.state = state;
   }
   ```

   }
   this is my main class:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   userDetails user = new userDetails();
   Address add = new Address();

   user.setUserName("Dipesh");
   user.setDob(new Time(0));
   add.setCity("vadodara");
   add.setState("gujarat");
   add.setStreet("raopura");



   SessionFactory sessionfactory = new     
    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
   Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();
   session.save(user);
   session.save(add);
   /*user = (userDetails)session.get(userDetails.class, 6);*/

   session.getTransaction().commit();
   session.close();
   ```

   }

I was trying to store the data but it was showing:

```
   ERROR: Field 'pincode' doesn't have a default value
   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:    
    could not execute statement

      at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
at org.hibernate.test.userTest.main(userTest.java:36)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'pincode' doesn't have a default    
value
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
at     
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2022)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1940)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1925)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
... 22 more
```

I had pincode in my address but it was showing an error so i removed it but still it showing that error.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table in your db has a field pincode for which you've not defined a default value and is not nullable. However, your entity has no mapping for that field and you are not sending a value  for this field. Thus, **java.sql.SQLException: Field 'pincode' doesn't have a default

value**

Comment: I dont have table named Address in my  database

Comment: I see that you're using  @Embeddable, missed that in the first reading. :P but your table does have a field pincode. Edited my answer.

Comment: I dont have anything in my userdetails table also

Comment: Please tell me where that pincode field is coming? The exception is propagated back from the DB.

Comment: I had that field in my address class but after showing an error on that field I had removed that field. now i dont have "pincode" word in my application. still it shows error on this

Comment: Check the definition of your table using MySQL CLI or WorkBench, you'll see a column 'pincode'. Either, make it nullable or provide a mapping for that column in your entity as suggested by @Rene Winkler in his anwer.

Comment: sorry!! I was cecking in different database. I have a column pincode in user_details. I have deleted it but now it is showing org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernet.src.Address error

Comment: How is your hibernate configuration defined? Can you check it?

Comment: Look in your configuration - 
1. if you are doing a scan by 'packagesToScan' then add the package of that Address enitty if not already there
2. If you are doing it by defining 'annotatedClasses' property then add a new value with the fully qualified name of that entity

Comment: I am using annotated classes and I have used fully qualified names of both of entities

Comment: Remove this line from your code

 session.save(add);

Comment: It is inside your main method

Comment: yess.... thanx a lot. I was stuck from last 2 hours. That was the error. I had `session.save(add)`  line in my main class. can you please explain what is the reason that we cant use that line?

Comment: Using Embedded, you embed that Embeddable entity in your Entity class, which makes it add columns for the embedded entity in same table of your Entity class and there is no such persistable entity with a table mapped that corresponds to that Embeddable.

Answer (score 1):

1) Adapt your entity that it includes the field "pincode"

```
@Entity
@Table (name="UserDetails")
public class userDetails {
...
@Column(name="pincode", columnDefinition="Number(10) default '34562'")
int pincode;
...
```

2) or alter the underlying table so that the pincode field has a default value:

```
 ALTER TABLE user_details MODIFY pincode NUMBER(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Number(10) is just chosen as an example. Replace this by the variable type of pincode.

Comment: I do not have address table in my database because I want to embedd it with userdetails

Comment: my user_details table is empty

Comment: sorry!! I was cecking in different database. I have a column pincode in user_details. I have deleted it but now it is showing `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernet.src.Address` error

Comment: Have you configured the hibernate configuration fil? It must define the entity class:
<mapping class="org.hibernet.src.UserDetails"/>
<mapping class="org.hibernet.src.Address"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72599/discussion-between-gotchha-and-rene-winkler).

Answer (score 1):

I had same error as **org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement** where i forgot to initialize session factory.

**Initializing(as follow) session factory resolved my issue.**

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```